# Dealing with AWS Elastic Beanstalk Multi-container databases and persistent storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I'm new to both Elastic Beanstalk, EC2 and Docker and spent the last couple of weeks researching and playing around with it. I have a few questions that I'm finding difficult to find answers to elsewhere.

One thing I like is that I am able to run `eb local run` to boot a local environment of what will be running in production. This seems to work well until it comes to databases.

1) As far as I understand Elastic Beanstalk spawns instances running the containers inside, which could result in having multiple databases if Elastic Beanstalk spawns multiple instances? Is this correct?

2) Is it better to use AWS RDS in production and then have an external database container locally?

3) In terms of persisting data, I read that EBS can only mount to one EC2 instance, how do people handle storing user files, or do they have their application push to a service such as S3 directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this is stated anywhere but I am fairly sure AWS does not intent for you to use EB's multi-container to run databases or anything that should run only once on your system. As their examples show, it is for you to have better control what the front end server will be.

If you want to run databases, or store files, you will either move to AWS ECS where you can better control this, or use multiple EB environment (e.g. create a worker-tier, single instance environment for running the database)

> One thing I like is that I am able to run eb local run to boot a local environment of what will be running in production. This seems to work well until it comes to databases.

I have not used `eb local run` and instead use docker-compose, which allows me to properly run a proper environment locally, including my databases. Yes, you may need to duplicate some information between the docker-compose file, and the Dockerrun file, but once you set it up, you will see how powerful it is. Because you are still sharing the Dockerfiles, you can still assume things will run in a similar enough way once deployed.

> 1) As far as I understand Elastic Beanstalk spawns instances running the containers inside, which could result in having multiple databases if Elastic Beanstalk spawns multiple instances? Is this correct?

Yes, I think that is correct. EB assumes you will use RDS or dynamodb or something else, already centralized and managed.

> 2) Is it better to use AWS RDS in production and then have an external database container locally?

Yes, and by the way, rather than having EB manage the creation of the database, I find it a better practice for you to manually instantiate it so that it stays persistent after you kill your EB environments.

> 3) In terms of persisting data, I read that EBS can only mount to one EC2 instance, how do people handle storing user files, or do they have their application push to a service such as S3 directly?

Yes, using S3 is the way to go for multiple reasons, but mostly because AWS manages and you can scale without you having to worry about it. In fact, you want your client to get or even post the files directly on S3, so your server does not have to do any work (note the server may need to sign the URL but that is about it).

If you really have an issue against S3 (for whatever reason), then you will also (like with the database) create a second, single instance EB environment with EBS to ensure you have a single instance. But compared to the S3 solution it won't scale very far, and will in fact be much more expensive than using S3.